# "Secondly, it improves my mental health by taking my mind off my problems and instead uses it to focus on the sport I'm playing"

Tags: sentence-construction

> Secondly, it improves my mental health by taking my mind off my problems and instead uses it to focus on the sport I'm playing

The first "it" refers to "playing sports", the second "it" refers to "my mind"

My English teacher said that this sentence wasn't correct because I used the word "instead" wrong.

Did I use it correctly?

Comment: Hi, welcome to ELL! Please keep in mind that proofreading questions are off-topic and will be closed. So I have edited your question accordingly to make it more on-topic.

Comment: It’s a hard sentence to parse. I am not sure what your teacher’s exact problem was but it is a bad sentence that is trying to do too much and confusing to read. If your teacher is wrong because your sentence confused them that’s the lesson to take away. Perhaps “Sport improves my mental health. It takes my mind off my problems by letting me focus on the sport I’m playing.” Never be afraid of using short and snappy sentences.

Comment: It is correct and fairly understandable. Do not forget a full-stop (or period) at the end of the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

> It improves my mental health by taking my mind off my problems and instead uses it to focus on the sport I'm playing.

Your teacher is right - you haven't used "instead" quite correctly.

"Instead" should be used when you are showing something to be a *substitute or equivalent* to something else. In your example, you haven't presented two interchangeable things.

Consider this example:

> I eat plant-based products instead of meat.

Here is a direct substitute - two things that the first person "I" could *eat*. They can eat meat, they can also eat plant-based alternatives. They are both alternative actions for the person.

In your example, you use the expression "*taking* my mind off my problems". The alternative you present to this is "*uses* it to focus...". This isn't an alternative for "it" (the sport), as it does *both*. The sport takes your mind off your problems **and** it makes your mind focus on the game.

You could use "instead" if you present the two as alternatives for the *mind*. For example:

> It improves my mental health by taking my mind off my problems and focusing it on the sport I'm playing instead.